# GREP - Regex +(plus) vs. *(star) performance

Tags: regex, performance, grep

Simple question, say I have two regular expressions

```
rtmp.*?\b/
rtmp.+?\b/
```

It seems to be negligible difference if any on the tests I have done.

I understand the technical difference between the two expressions. In my case either will do. As the question states I am simply asking about the performance difference, if any. One difference I noticed is that `+` requires `egrep`

```
 grep 'rtmp.*?\b/'
egrep 'rtmp.+?\b/'
```

Comment: they are used for different things?

Comment: @userunknown The question mark is used to make the `+` or `*` "non-greedy" -- i.e., they will consume as few characters as possible (and still make the whole regex match), rather than as many as possible (the default).  See http://www.itworld.com/nl/perl/01112001

Comment: If this performance is critical, I'd say `rtmp\w*+` should be the fastest, but don't expect too much - especially since you're only matching a few characters. In general, lazy quantifiers mean more backtracking, which is somewhat costly, but a possessive quantifier  *cannot* backtrack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These two expressions:

```
rtmp.*?\b/
rtmp.+?\b/
```

match different things. `*` means "zero or more of the previous expression" (i.e. any number), `+` means "one or more of the previous expression". So `.*?` matches any number of any characters in non-greedy mode and `.+?` matches any positive number of any characters in non-greedy mode.

The speed difference is immaterial, use the expression that matches your intent.

Answer (score 2):

Choose the one that is more appropriate for your needs;
The perofrmance difference is negligible.

`*` The asterisk indicates there is zero or more of the preceding element.
`+` The plus sign indicates there is one or more of the preceding element.

Comment: @StevenPenny. I answered that, the difference is negligible... :)

Answer (score 0):

One difference I noticed is that `+` requires `grep -E`

```
grep 'http.*f4m'

grep -E 'http.+f4m'
```